# AchartEngine disable only zoomout button

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AchartEngine to draw graphs,
is it possible to disable only the zoom out button ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the original zoom buttons with below code

```
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
```

and write your own button just to zoom-in inside your xml file and do something like below:

```
ImageButton btnZoomIn= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoomIn);

btnZoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChartView.zoomIn();

        }
});
```